# tf2 transformPose in C++

Tags: ros, c++, posestamped, tf2, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm used to the `transformPose()` method and similar from `tf`. However, the tf listener was apparently missing some static poses so I switched to `tf2`. Now I can get the TransformStamped but I'm struggling to actually apply it to a pose. So, how do you apply a TransformStamped to a PoseStamped?

The tf2 [tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf2%20listener%20%28C%2B%2B%29) don't seem to cover this crucial aspect. (they should) Apologies if there's an obvious answer that I missed.

[The Python version of this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/95791/tf-transformpoint-equivalent-on-tf2/)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261419/tf2-transformpose-in-c++/) by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2331 on 2017-05-09

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks to @dhood's answer on [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/95791/tf-transformpoint-equivalent-on-tf2/), I dug through tf2_geometry_msgs and found `doTransform()`. I'll probably edit the tf2 tutorials to mention this. Here's the gist of getting a TransformStamped and applying it to a PoseStamped with tf2:

```
   #include <tf2_geometry_msgs/tf2_geometry_msgs.h>

   #include <tf2_ros/transform_listener.h>
```

.
.
.

```
tf2_ros::Buffer tf_buffer;
tf2_ros::TransformListener tf2_listener(tf_buffer);
geometry_msgs::TransformStamped base_link_to_leap_motion; // My frames are named "base_link" and "leap_motion"

base_link_to_leap_motion = tf_buffer.lookupTransform("leap_motion", "base_link", ros::Time(0), ros::Duration(1.0) );

tf2::doTransform(robot_pose, robot_pose, base_link_to_leap_motion); // robot_pose is the PoseStamped I want to transform
```

---

Originally posted by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) with karma: 2331 on 2017-05-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2017-05-11**:
And a more in-depth [tutorial.](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Using%20stamped%20datatypes%20with%20tf2::MessageFilter)